# can't play audio files in my wordpress theme

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, mp3, embed

I can play .mp3 files in the *twenty fourteen theme* but not in my *current theme*.  When I look at the source code I see that:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='\wp-includes/js/mediaelement/mediaelement-and-player.min.js?ver=2.13.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var _wpmejsSettings = {"pluginPath":"\/wp-includes\/js\/mediaelement\/"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='\wp-includes/js/mediaelement/wp-mediaelement.js?ver=3.8.1'></script>
```

This is missing in the source code for my *current theme* but not from the *twenty fourteen theme*.

I imagine I need to put a call to this script in my theme but I'm not sure where or how I should do it.

I've tried inserting that piece of code into the head section of my header.php file but it didn't work!

Comment: You added the link to the script, but does the script exist in that location?

Comment: Yes, when I click on the link I get `/* global mejs, _wpmejsSettings */
(function ($) {
 // add mime-type aliases to MediaElement plugin support
 mejs.plugins.silverlight[0].types.push('video/x-ms-wmv');
 mejs.plugins.silverlight[0].types.push('audio/x-ms-wma');

 $(function () {
  var settings = {};

  if ( typeof _wpmejsSettings !== 'undefined' )
   settings.pluginPath = _wpmejsSettings.pluginPath;

  $('.wp-audio-shortcode, .wp-video-shortcode').mediaelementplayer( settings );
 });

}(jQuery));`